# Is their any way to call any web service just before delete app from iPhone device

Tags: ios

I want to call a web service for de-authorize device, when user delete app from iPhone.

Comment: may be it is helping to you ->>>>>  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412785/call-status-change-web-service-when-my-app-is-deleted

Answer (score 1):

No Event is fired when App is deleted from the iPhone. So I am sorry, But you cannot call any webservice or do anything at the time of deletion of App.

Comment: I know it bro but i am talking about any alternative solution for this.

Comment: @Sanjeevsharma What you can do is, You can create a Varialble which will uniquely identify whether the app is installed for the first or second time (Which means it has been deleted once and then reinstalled again). What say?

Comment: how can we do above solution?