# Call status change web-service when my App is deleted

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, web-services, background

In my application , i works with web-services and when user log in into my app my app is sending a request with status 1 means loged in and when on log out button click sending a request with status 0.

Now problem is , when user removes app from devices , status in my server is remain 1(log in) , hence other user can see him available while his app is not in device. so is there any way by which i can send request when my app removes from device (i don't think it is possible) or is there any other way that i can do in my backend side ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is push notification enabled to your application?

Comment: Location based service activated in your application?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to call a web service when the user deleting the app from an ios device. There are three methods to came to know that whether your application is there in user's ios device. But there are few limitations also.

1. **Activate Push notification**: By doing this, device will get registered with Apple's push notification service. When user delete the app from device, the registration will be revoked from APNS server and through the APNS feedback service, you can get to know whether the application is existing. (Limitation: If the user did not agree with receiving push notifications, then the app will not be registered with APNS and you never came to know that whether application is existing or not)
2. **Activate Location Based service**: If your application enables location based service, then your application will get periodic location updates in a location delegate method. In this delegate, you can call a webservice and keep update the status of user even the application is in background. (Limitation: If user disables the location update, then your server will not get info about user status)
3. **Periodically Call a Webservice From you app**: This is possible only if your app is active. (Limitation: When you application pushed in to background, your application will be in suspended mode, so it will not possible to call webservice)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry Unfortunately Apple not provide any method that user Uninstall app from user's device, There is no such method.

When user delete any application device does give the alert "Do you want to delete this application" with option "Delete" and "Cancel". You don't have to write any specific code for this.

I just assume that There is one method in which you can find out when user is about to delete your app. That is you need to implement push notification Apple server will inform you when you try to push to an uninstalled instance. Other than that there's no way to detect it but i am not sure its helpful or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this from within the app. You would want to do something like have a periodic task which runs on the backend, checking the last activity date of logged in users and setting them to 'not available' after some configured period of inactivity. This will probably require some changes to the backend to record last activity date and a change to the app so that while it's open it sends a periodic 'heartbeat' to the backend. You probably want to make the timeout quite big (say 15 minutes, big enough to not have a large impact on performance).